# D7 Image Field Paths - Using a custom Path for Each Image Style

Tags: 7, tokens, files, media

I am looking to have an image get dynamic name for each style that is generated by the system.

Currently I am using tokens to generate an md5 hash for the file name, but for each style (eg small/med/larg/original) the same name is held accross each image, and a new md5 hash is **not generated** for each new style.

`default/files/styles/medium/public/490137c8f3d68c0a95efa0ed24d8efc0/fd6b143edb9fa9da62707eb7aee3f40eCosta%20Rican%20Frog.jpg`

`sites/default/files/490137c8f3d68c0a95efa0ed24d8efc0/fd6b143edb9fa9da62707eb7aee3f40eCosta%20Rican%20Frog.jpg`

Ultimately I am trying to control access to the original files, though would like them to be public just not guessable, so they are easily shareable, if someone would like to.

I have tried to use [File path module](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths), but still no options based on style (that I can tell).

I am open to anyway really, modules or some php customization, ideas?

Thanks!